# Haskell implementation of rpn using foldr

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a reverse Polish notation evaluator using foldr and this is what I have so far :

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int] 
step (x * y):ys "*" = (x:y:ys)
step (x + y):ys "+" = (x:y:ys)
step (y - x):ys "-" = (x:y:ys)
step xs numberString = read numberString:xs

rpnRec ::[String] -> Int   
rpnRec [] = 1                                          
rpnRec = reverse .foldr step []
```

I have tried to resolve the error by swapping the positions of this : (x * y):ys and this (x:y:ys)
but I keep getting this error:

```
Rpn.hs:14:7: error: Parse error in pattern: x * y
   |
14 | step (x * y):ys "*" = (x:y:ys)
   |       ^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

any help would be appreciated on how to resolve this. Thank you

Comment: The reason this will not work is because the result of `foldr step []` will be a `[Int]` (check the types), not an `Int`. Furthermore you can not use `(x * y)` as pattern, since `(*)` is *not* a data constructor.

Comment: You should use `foldl'` for this, not `foldr`, for the reasons I explained at [How to define a function using foldr for rpn in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59590468/7509065).

Comment: Also, are you in the same class as [THE K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12592710/the-k) and [ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10554824/ray)? Is your professor actually teaching you anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems here. The first one is that you swap "input" and "output" in your `step` function. Indeed if you encounter a multiplication (`"*"`) you pop two items from the stack, and push the result of the multiplication on the stack. The `step` function should thus look like:

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int] 
step (x:y:ys) "*" = x*y:ys
step (x:y:ys) "+" = x+y:ys
step (x:y:ys) "-" = x-y:ys
step xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

The parenthesis for the `(x:y:ys)` are necessary here, since we use the same parameter: a list of `Int`s.

Furtermore you can not write `foldr step []` and expect that it will yield an `Int`. The `foldr` will return the accumulator, and that is a list of `Int`s, hence `foldr step [] somelist :: [Int]`. You can use for example `head` to obtain the first element.

The type of the accumulator and the element should be swapped, we can make use of [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) to flip the two parameters.

Finally you should reverse the list of strings, not the output, thus the function should look like:

```
rpnRec :: [String] -> Int
rpnRec = safeHead . foldr (flip step) [] . reverse
    where safeHead [] = 1
          safeHead (x:_) = x
```

For example:

```
Prelude> rpnRec ["2", "3", "*", "5", "+"]
11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]
step (x * y):ys "*" = (x:y:ys)
step (x + y):ys "+" = (x:y:ys)
step (y - x):ys "-" = (x:y:ys)
step xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

Try saying

```
step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y) : ys
```

The same for the other operators. The last line of `step` looks OK.